# Flip all text in an HTML using 'BeautifulSoup' and 'upsidedown'

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm looking for a way to safely flip all text in an HTML using the python libraries `BeautifulSoup` and `upsidedown`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import upsidedown

soup = BeautifulSoup('''<p>Paragraph1</p> <p>Paragraph2</p>'''
, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.findAll('p')

for tag in tags:
    for c in tag.contents:
        c.string = upsidedown.transform(c.string)

print(soup)
```

Expected output:
`<p>ІɥdɐɹƃɐɹɐԀ</p> <p>ᘔɥdɐɹƃɐɹɐԀ</p>`

Actual output:
`<p>Paragraph1</p> <p>Paragraph2</p>`

I would also like some guidance on how to flip text in more complicated HTMLs.
For example if I have nested tags, I don't want to flip the tags themselves, because that would make the HTML syntax invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `replace_with()` method.
You just have to change the following line:

```
c.string = upsidedown.transform(c.string)
```

by

```
c.string.replace_with(upsidedown.transform(c.string))
```

**FULL CODE:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import upsidedown

soup = BeautifulSoup('''<p>Paragraph1</p> <p>Paragraph2</p>'''
, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.findAll('p')

for tag in tags:
    for c in tag.contents:
        c.string.replace_with(upsidedown.transform(c.string))
print(soup)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   <p>ІɥdɐɹƃɐɹɐԀ</p> <p>ᘔɥdɐɹƃɐɹɐԀ</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, this answered my primary question.